# How to declare structure as return type of typealias in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, type-alias

I am importing c function from the **.dylib** in swift package using **dlopen** function . c function (i.e uplink function ) will return structure . for calling **c function from swift** i need to create typealias of c function .

C struture

```
typedef struct Uplink  { long _handle; } UplinkRef;
```

C function declaration

```
extern UplinkRef uplink(UplinkConfig p0, char** p1);
```

uplink function is returning UplinkRef structure.

UplinkRef struct in swift

```
struct UplinkRef{
 var _handle = -1
}
```

so , i have to create typealias in swift so that i can call c function

```
typealias uplink = @convention(c) ()->UplinkRef
```

1) How can i define structure (i.e UplinkRef) as returned type of typealise ?

2) How can i define structure (i.e UplinkRef) as argument of typealias ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `struct UplinkRef` is,

```
struct UplinkRef {
    var handle = -1
}
```

then,

**1.** `UplinkRef` as *return type* in `typealias`

```
typealias Uplink1 = (()->(UplinkRef))
```

**2.** `UplinkRef` as *parameter type* in `typealias`

```
typealias Uplink2 = ((UplinkRef)->())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can solve this generally:

- Go to the header file where the C function is declared.
- Select the "Generated Interface" assistant view.

Then you'll see that the `uplink()` function is imported to Swift as

```
public func uplink(_ p0: UplinkConfig,
                   _ p1: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!) -> UplinkRef
```

so that the correct type alias for the dynamically loaded C function is

```
typealias UplinkFunc = @convention(c) (UplinkConfig,
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?) -> UplinkRef
```

*Alternatively,* add

```
typedef typeof(uplink) UplinkFunc;
```

to the bridging header file, this is imported to Swift as the correct type alias for the function type.

*In any case* you should define the C structures in C header files which are imported to Swift, and not (re)define them in Swift. This guarantees that same memory layout is correctly preserved.

Comment: @ShivamKumar: You asked the same question on the Swift forum now: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-declare-structure-as-return-type-of-typealias-in-swift/28419. If anything is unclear then let us know and we'll try to help.

Comment: How can i import c structure in swift and use them in swift for calling c function ?

Comment: @ShivamKumar: You define the struct in a .h file, and include that .h file in the bridging header file.

Comment: cannot use bridging file in SPM package . any other suggestion ? Thanks! for replying .